# Set Image ListView With If Statement

Tags: android, listview

I have an image listview with a dynamic list items length, I have only 3 images however the images must only be set on each item IF value of status is OK, OFFLINE or PENDING, how can I use IF ELSE IF and ELSE to set one of the 3 images in each list view items, a sample of my code below:

```
Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.round_green,
            R.drawable.round_red,
            R.drawable.round_grey,
        };

ContactsAdapter adapter = new ContactsAdapter(this, itemTitle, itemStatus, imageId);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setOnItemClickListener(this);       

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            View row=convertView;
            if(row==null)
            {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_item, parent, false);      
            }

            TextView tvTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Title);
            TextView tvStatus = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Status);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            tvTitle.setText(Title.get(position));
            tvStatus.setText(Status.get(position));
            imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]); //this must set either image A or B or C depending on value of text view status which can either be OK, OFFLINE or PENDING 

            return row;
            }
```

Comment: if you are using custom listview then provide the getView()method's code

Comment: edited to show getView()method

Comment: Where are you checking the status i think this code will put first image on first position second image on second position and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can I use IF ELSE IF and ELSE to set one of the 3 images in each list
>   view items

We can do it without using `if-else` ladder, using `HashMap`.

Use OK, OFFLINE or PENDING as key and `drawable`  id's as value in HashMap:

```
Map<String, Integer> drawableMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
drawableMap.put("ok",R.drawable.round_green);
drawableMap.put("pending",R.drawable. round_grey);
drawableMap.put("offline",R.drawable. round_red);
```

Now use `Status.get(position)` as key for retrieving drawable id:

```
imageView.setImageResource(drawableMap.get(Status.get(position).toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: agreed with this one. You can even use a switch clause checking status and use the drawable directly. I dont see why you should use an array when you're passing final ids

Answer (score 0):

In the adapter ContactsAdapter  got to inside of getView method and make the condition like

```
if(value.equal("OK"))
{
//set your image...
}
else if(value.equal("OFFLINE"))
{
//set your image...
}
else if(value.equals(PENDING))
{
//set your image...
}
```